# Get single elements of list of list of list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

I have a list in python like

```
l=[1,2,[3,4,5],[[4,2,4],[4,7,8]]]
```

I want using a set to get all unique values, but this fails

```
set(l)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

So anybody help please? Want to use set with list of list of list etc etc THX

Comment: What you need is to [flatten the list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: Why do you have unevenly nested data?

Comment: Thank you very much! That code works when using with set! Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to 'unwind', or flatten the nested structure before you can put this in a set. You can use a generator for that to keep this efficient for large lists:

```
def flatten(lst):
    for element in lst:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            for subelement in flatten(element):
                yield subelement
        else:
            yield element
```

then use that generator on your list `l` to create a set:

```
set(flatten(l))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach, you flatten the list first before you apply the set operation on it.

```
import collections

def flat_list(tlist):
   if isinstance(tlist, collections.Iterable):
      return [j for i in tlist for j in flat_list(i)]
   else:
      return [tlist]
```

then:

```
myl=[1,2,[3,4,5],[[4,2,4],[4,7,8]]]

print set(flat_list(myl))
```

gives:

```
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8])
```

@MartijnPieters approach with a generator will work more efficiently with very *large* lists than this [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) based approach.